# Ubuntu 14.04 unable to connect to wired internet

Tags: 14.04, internet, wired

After I upgraded from 12.04 to 14.04, I am not able to connect to Internet. The out put of `ifconfig` is

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:19:d1:6e:fb:1a  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:174 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:174 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:13095 (13.0 KB)  TX bytes:13095 (13.0 KB)
```

I tried to add

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

as some threads suggested but no effect. Thanks

Comment: Your computer isn't even assigned an IP address by the DHCP server/router. At the risk of sounding obvious: Is DHCP set as connection method in the network configuration (e. g. instead of “Manual“) and is the Ethernet cable still attached to a working router? You can check the physical connection by looking at the small LED next to most Ethernet ports. If it's lit, the connection is up.

Comment: @OP, try using static IP addresses and see how that goes

Comment: I tried, but no success

Comment: @DavidFoerster, yes DHCP is set as the connection method. and I can see the green LED flashing while I connect the cable.

Answer (score 0):

Use the command

> ip addr

You'll get something like:

```
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether d0:27:e5:4a:cc:e1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 10.160.11.152/23 brd 10.160.11.255 scope global eth0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe10::d367:e5ff:fe4a:cce1/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Notice the "UP" after "state". This will tell you whether your cable is plugged in correctly or not. If it's DOWN, first try unplugging and then plugging the cable back in. If that doesn't work, try:

> sudo ip link set dev eth0 up

Check ip addr again. If it's still down, it's most probably a hardware problem (bad cable, bad switch etc)

Comment: But I am able to connect with the same cable and switch on my laptop

Comment: executed the command as you suggested. The out put is

Comment: 1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default 
        link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
        inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
        inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
        link/ether 00:19:d1:6e:fb:1a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

It shows "UP" after the "state"

Comment: According to that output, your network is down. If you are sure your switch and cable are good, type the following command: `sudo ip link set dev eth0 up` , then run the previous commands again to check your state